# Assign struct pointer to another struct pointer does not work?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I implemented an iterative version of preorder tree traversal like following:

```
...


void push(struct TreeNode* node)
{
   if(node!=NULL)
   {
       top = top + 1;
       stack[top].node = node;
       stack[top].val = node->val;
   }
}

void pop(struct TreeNode* node, int* retSz)
{
   if(stack[top].node!=NULL)
   {
       *retSz = *retSz + 1;
       OutputArray = (int*)(realloc(OutputArray, (*retSz)*sizeof(int)));
       OutputArray[*retSz-1] = stack[top].val;

       node = stack[top].node;

       top = top - 1;
       
   }
}


int* preorderTraversal(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize){
   
   ...
   
   //start
   push(root);
   
   //process
   while(!isEmpty())
   {
       pop(root, returnSize);
       push(root->right);
       push(root->left);
   }
   

   return OutputArray;

}
```

I found in push(),

```
stack[top].node = node;
```

it do work, but in pop()

```
node = stack[top].node;
```

This line does not work,
the node still points to the same one.

But after I changed it to

```
node->val = stack[top].node->val;
node->left = stack[top].node->left;
node->right = stack[top].node->right;
```

or

```
*node= *(stack[top].node);
```

Then the program works normally.

Can anyone point out the problem ?

Comment: `node` in your `pop` is a local variable.  Assigning it in a function will not make any difference outside. OTOH, dereferencing it and assigning is actually changing the values it is *pointing* to.

Comment: `node = stack[top].node;` only affect the local variable `node` in `pop()`. It has no effect to the calling function.

Comment: If you want to return a thing from a function, consider this syntax: `return aThing;`. Adjust function declaration accordingly

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Thanks for your reply :) It’s clear to me now.